# Smell the Coffee

Tags: evaporation

Do non-water particles of coffee evaporate or leave the surface of hot coffee over time? Are they some sort of carbon-based molecules? Are they carried into the air by the evaporating water molecules?  Is this what allows us to smell coffee ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about chemistry.  Try http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In a word, yes. A quick google search will show you a variety of the different chemicals that give coffee its aroma and flavor. However, the folks over at chemistry.stackexchange.com may be able to provide you with a more satisfactory answer.

Comment: Jerry and Tyler: I look at chemistry as being a part of physics.  Any thoughts on whether the water evaporation carries the coffee aroma moleecules or are the coffee aroma molecules evaporating themselves?